# Create Zend controller

Tags: zend-framework

I am using ubunto & want to create zend controller, 7months ago i created about 5 controllers in my application & it works fine but when now i try to create another one using

```
sajid@salman-laptop:/var/www/vcred$ zf.sh create controller verifier
```

It show error message like:

> ```
>  An Error Has Occurred
> ```
>
> String could not be parsed as XML
>
> ```
> Command Line Console Tool v1.8.4
> Details for action "Create" and provider "Controller"
>   Controller
>     zf create controller name index-action-included[=1] module
> ```

Help please.

Comment: You don't _need_ to use Zend_Tool for this. You can always add the controllers by hand.

Answer (score 2):

old-school method : manually add the new controller file to the directory - i've never used Zend_Tool.

Comment: +1 I have a blank controller template with some general methods ready so I can just edit the name and copy and paste it when needed to create a new controller manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Zend_Tool, they have solved a lot of bugs in the last versions. At this time [the 1.10.1 version is the latest release](http://framework.zend.com/download/current/), compared to your 1.8.4.